# Saving / Loading Data Java app

Tags: java, filesystems, text-files, savechanges

I have a small application in Java that uses a lot of quantities. I would like to save input from the users so that they wouldn't have to re-enter all the data each time they ran the app. I was thinking of having text files and overriding them with the new data each time something changed. Is this correct?

Comment: do you want to save some information like user settings ?your approach is correct .but i think easy and best way is use property file instead of plain textfile .take a look http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha I guess you could consider them user settings but they're really just a bunch of numbers used in some formulas. I'll take a look at property file. Thanks!